# Remote dd backup with ssh

Tags: unix, ssh, dd

I am currently using a combination of dd, gzip and nc to remote backup the flash of an arm board.

> dd if=/dev/nand conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c -9 | nc 192.168.0.123 8000

I'd like to ask whether there is an efficient way to omit nc and transfer the data via ssh.

Furthermore, I am also looking for a solution where the backup process is initiated by the 'backup server'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines?

```
dd if=/dev/nand conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c -9 | ssh user@server 'cat - > backup.gz'
```

Comment: Seems nice. I have added another scenario to the question.

Comment: ssh user@board 'dd if=/dev/nand conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c -9' > backup.gz; This should work, right?

Comment: You can also add the -C flag to your ssh command. This will enable compression in the ssh connection

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that sync is a good conversion flag to use.  The dd man page says:

```
   sync   pad  every  input block with NULs to ibs-size; when used with block or unblock, pad
          with spaces rather than NULs
```

I don't think you want to pad with anything.  Perhaps this was meant to be passed to iflags instead:

```
   dsync  use synchronized I/O for data

   sync   likewise, but also for metadata
```

or perhaps direct instead:

```
   direct use direct I/O for data
```

which is slightly faster on my Cubieboard2's nand.